# Maven dependencies in different modules

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

I have a multi module project in IntelliJ IDEA (over 20 modules).
I never used a dependency management tool, all of my module's dependencies jars are imported via a local repository.

I created a pom.xml for each module, and added the dependencies via central maven repo.

I am getting `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError` and `java.lang.StackOverflowError` on my pom.xml files as seen in [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5sY8t.png)

I assume that this is happening because some modules share the same dependencies, and also depend on each other - which creates some sort of overload.

For example, I imported the same 100 dependencies both in module 'A' and module 'B',
and module 'B' also has module 'A' as a dependency. I guess that this is not the right approach and this is what causes the problem.

How should I approach this issue? can I somehow tell maven to take only one instance of the dependencies and somehow ignore duplicates?

Comment: Do you consider sharing your pom.xml to really certify this is the issue ? In case the issue is what you identify as cyclic dependencies, how does that work ? The whole idea of a module is to ensure there are no cyclic dependencies and you can develop as in a "supply chain" and you identify your dependencies as BOM (bill of materials) for your module. In that case, you correctly identify that the possible mess is one of the concerns. I'm not sure the errors you point out are due directly to the issue you identified.

Comment: So what happens if you just build on command line?

Comment: The OOM could be related to https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-273726 As a workaround try increasing IDE memory heap: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/increasing-memory-heap.html But the `StackOverflowError` issue needs to be investigated separately. Are there any errors in [idea.log](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/directories-used-by-the-ide-to-store-settings-caches-plugins-and-logs.html#logs-directory)?